# Is SharePoint website vulnerable for CVE-2019-0604 when parameter shows up?

Tags: sharepoint

Introduction:

First of all I would like to state I am legally pen testing (as an absolute beginner and hobbyist) a website.
This website makes use of SharePoint, and because of that I am for the first time looking into known vulnerabilities relating to SharePoint.

Question:

When `/_layouts/15/picker.aspx?PickerDialogType=Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ItemPickerDialog, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c` can be added after the domain and this gives the screen "An error occurred. Administrators, see the server log for more information.".
And the parameter `ctl00%24PlaceHolderDialogBodySection%24ctl05%24hiddenSpanData` shows up in the intercepted request.

Does this mean the page is vulnerable to CVE-2019-0604?

I do not have the skills yet to exploit it. But I would like to inform the webmaster when this is a problem.

Or does it not yet mean anything if this steps exists on the webpage?

- TLDR:
  When`/_layouts/15/picker.aspx?PickerDialogType=Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ItemPickerDialog, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c` can be added to a domain and the parameter `ctl00%24PlaceHolderDialogBodySection%24ctl05%24hiddenSpanData`is visible when you intercept the request. Does this mean the webpage is vulnerable to CVE-2019-0604?
  Or does this not mean anything yet (I have not the skills or confidence to test further).

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean the page is vulnerable to CVE-2019-0604?

No, this page and parameters is available also in patched SharePoint server.

The ways i know to check if this server is vulnerable or not:

- Check SharePoint version is updated or no for CVE-2019-0604.
- Perform the exploit and see your RCE is applied or not. (you could find exploit module for CVE-2019-0604 in GitHub)

Hope this help :)